# Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using visual studio 2017(Professional). Last few day's i got follows error. I tried multiple way's but can't resolved.

Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error. HttpRequestException encountered.    An error occurred while sending the request. HttpRequestException encountered.    An error occurred while sending the request. cannot spawn /C/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory could not read Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/49058547/4758119

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48952151/4758119

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't pull or push with Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952151/cant-pull-or-push-with-team-explorer-in-visual-studio-2017)